# Where in Visual Studio can I specify the switch `-c`?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I learned that to debug a Windows service in Visual Studio 2015 IDE, I can launch the service from IDE using the “-c” command-line switch. This enables the service to run as a console application.

Where in Visual Studio can I specify the switch `-c`?

Is `-c` a switch for the debugger?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you learned that?

Comment: This is not a built-in feature.  Maybe you have somebody else's code to do this but then you'd mention that.

Comment: I suggest you search the service's source code for support for the "-c" switch, most likely you will find it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Windows Service debugging, but if you simply want to add a command line argument that is done by right clicking the project and navigating like this:

Properties > Debug > Command Line Arguments

Comment: I use this in tandem with CommandLineParser Nuget Package to add in some extra stuff sometimes - works nice!

Comment: I believe (though I may be wrong) that the question is asking about somethign built-in, not how to add command line switches yourself.

Comment: This is probably the right answer IF we assume whoever wrote the service, also provided support (in the code) for the -c switch, to run the code as a console application instead.

Comment: The question wasn't very clear, I just went out on a limb and figured they were asking about adding command line parameters in Visual Studio.